# Seat map visibility

Tags: amadeus

When I query seat maps for certain flights, I find that much of the seatmap comes back with "blocked" status. I can confirm with various other sources (airline webpage, ExpertFlyer, etc.) that many of the seats showing up as blocked in the Amadeus API are actually open.

One example is the following query for EWR-LHR flights on UA. I run this as a GET query on the flight-offers API and then pass the results to the seat map API.

```
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=JFK&destinationLocationCode=LHR&departureDate=2020-12-18&adults=1&nonStop=true&max=250
```

This comes back with rows 30-35 or so all "BLOCKED" status. Many of these seats are in reality open, but United may charge an extra fee to book them.

Is there a way to show actual seat availability or include the information on seats for purchase? Alternatively, can I specify the booking class in the query somehow? E.g. I wonder if I asked for a higher class of fare (e.g. full-fare Y) maybe no seat charge would be required (not completely familiar with UA's rules on this). Overall my goal is to see all actual available seats.

Answer (score 1):

The SeatMap Display API builds the aircraft seatmap based on specific flight offer. That’s why the information you get for the seat availability depends on the traveler class information. In the [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) you can define with the parameter `travelClass` the travel class; economy, premium economy, business or first class. Also, in the test environment it's normal to have discrepancies with other sources as the test environment doesn't contain the full and live data.